# How to specify the type of an "async as" variable?

Tags: angular, observable

I get the error `Argument of type '() => Observable<Device[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'` from this markup:

```
<div *ngIf="(deviceStoreService.getDevices | async) as devices">
  <tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <td>{{device.name}} <midi-keyboard [device]="device"></midi-keyboard></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

I get the same error from this markup:

```
<tr *ngFor="let device of (deviceStoreService.getDevices | async)">
  <td>{{device.name}} <midi-keyboard [device]="device"></midi-keyboard></td>
</tr>
```

I don't get the error if I assign a controller class member variable, with the markup:

```
<tr *ngFor="let device of (devices | async)">
  <td>{{device.name}} <midi-keyboard [device]="device"></midi-keyboard></td>
</tr>
```

and the controller class:

```
export class DeviceComponent implements OnInit {

  devices: Observable<Array<Device>>;

  constructor(
    private deviceStoreService: DeviceStoreService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.devices = this.deviceStoreService.getDevices();
  }
```

Why is this ?

Comment: Hi, the official reason for down-voting a question is because it shows little research effort, is poorly constructed, unclear or not useful. However, e are encouraged to post comments for specific reasons why we may have down-voted.

I believe someone downvoted as your title doesn't seem to make sense with relation to the rest of the post. (The only reason I say this is because I am not sure what the title should be)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the parens. If `getDevices` is a function, then

```
<div *ngIf="(deviceStoreService.getDevices() | async) as devices">
```

Comment: I think I'll keep the controller class way in fact, for calling the service from the template requires the service to be injected as public instead of private and there is no way of exposing the template defined devices array in the controller class so as to use it again like `this.devices$ = this.deviceStoreService.addDevice(device);`